# C++/CLI Conversion of byte* to Managed Byte[]

Tags: c++-cli

I'm in a C++/CLI project, and I have a `byte*` variable that I want to fully convert into a managed `array<byte>` as efficiently as possible.

Currently, the only way that I've seen is to manually create the managed `array<byte>` object, and then copy individual bytes from the `byte*` variable, as shown below:

```cpp
void Foo(byte* source, int bytesCount)
{
   auto buffer = gcnew array<byte>(bytesCount);

   for (int i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i)
   {
      buffer[i] = source[i];
   }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this more efficiently? Ideally, to not have to copy the memory at all.

If not, is there any way to do this more cleanly?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-copy(system-intptr-system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)

Comment: Maybe avoiding the copy is possible, but you have not given a single clue what you intend to do with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a managed array from an unmanaged buffer without copying.

However, you don't need to copy the individual bytes in a loop, though.  You can **pin** the managed array (see [`pin_ptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/pin-ptr-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170)) and then copy the bytes directly from the unmanaged buffer into the memory of the managed array, such as with `memcpy()` or equivalent.

```cpp
void Foo(byte* source, int bytesCount)
{
   auto buffer = gcnew array<byte>(bytesCount);

   {
      pin_ptr<byte> p = &buffer[0];
      byte *cp = p;
      memcpy(cp, source, bytesCount);
   }

   // use buffer as needed...
}
```

Comment: Do you mind giving some sample code?

Comment: Read the documentation: [How to: Pin Pointers and Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/how-to-pin-pointers-and-arrays?view=msvc-170)